# calling bat file using asp classic

Tags: batch-file, iis, asp-classic, window

Can anyone help me with this problem, i need to call/execute bat file. below are my codes for bat file and asp classic.

**test.bat**

```
    echo off
    start C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Texting\Notification.lnk
```

That test.bat will run a shortcut and call the application, that will update received file.

**sample.asp** this code is for classic asp

```
    <%

    dim fs,tfile,loc,locadd,loctime1,nameFile,wshell

    locadd = Month(Date)&Day(Date)&Year(Date)
    loctime1 =  stripNonNumeric(FormatDateTime(Now,3))
    nameFile = "\\85new\Accts85new\Texting\Reply\Karing\"
    loc = "\\85new\Accts85new\Texting\Reply\Karing\"&locadd&"_"&loctime1&".txt"
    set fs= Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set tfile=fs.CreateTextFile(loc)

    For Each Item in Request.QueryString
        tfile.Write Item &";"& Request.QueryString(Item)&"$&$"
    next

    tfile.close
    set tfile=nothing
    set fs=nothing

    Function stripNonNumeric(inputString)
        Set regEx = New RegExp
         regEx.Global = True
         regEx.Pattern = "\D"
         stripNonNumeric = regEx.Replace(inputString,"")
      End Function

    set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wshell.Run "cmd.exe /c C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Texting\test1.bat"
    set wshell = nothing

    %>
```

that **sample.asp** will get the value of parameters from querystring.

The code is working, no error received when i hit ENTER on the browser.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did the duplicate when you [asked last time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60033119/692942) not help?

Comment: Left a suggestion on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60033119/692942), please try not post duplicates especially after they have already been closed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033119/how-to-execute-bat-file-using-classic-asp#comment106442068_60033119

Answer (score 0):

Typically this should be done in another way, but assuming you understand the security implications of calling bat file from a web application, you need to try to [redirect output to a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to ensure it is executed and what is the output, i.e.

```
wshell.Run "test1.bat>debug.txt"
```

CreateObject("WScript.Shell") is executed in a separate process and you will not get any error in the browser, that's why your bat file needs to output its result somewhere.